# 2D variable through ndgrid Matlab

Tags: matlab, math, multidimensional-array, matlab-figure

Suppose you have a certain 2D of data inside a matrix M. You know that such a matrix represents a 2D function vs two variables x, y, which are two vectors. Here an example, with the corresponding workspace.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2Nj6.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/biFv3.png)

Now, I want to plot such a function M against the variables a = sin(x)cos(y)
b = sin(x)sin(y)

So, I have defined a grid in the following way:

```
[x_grid, y_grid] = ndgrid(x,y);
a_grid = sin(x_grid).*cos(y_grid);
b_grid = sin(x_grid).*sin(y_grid);
```

Now, how can i plot M vs a,b? If I write:

```
mesh(a_grid, b_grid, M)
xlabel('a')
blabel('b')
```

I get the following graph:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKBl2.png)

I do not know if my procedure is correct, but I think it isn't. In fact, such a procedure assumes that the rows of M corresponds to the vector a, and its columns to the vector b. It isn't, as both a and b are functions of x,y.

Which is the correct procedure?

Comment: I *think* you want to interpolate M at a and b, then plot the result vs a and b. But I’m not sure because your question is not very clear.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Yes, exactly

Comment: Then use [`interp2`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp2.html).

Comment: @CrisLuengo Could you help me in writing the code to use it in my specific case, where there is a change of coordinate (it is not simply an interpolation, because I'd like to get a Matrix M whose rows correspond to a and columns to b).

Comment: It is simply interpolation. Follow the examples on the documentation page I linked, input coordinates are x and y, output coordinates are a and b. This is trivial, try and see.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you'd like to have three plots in the same window. This means you need to call `mesh()` multiple times. As you correctly said, the first two arguments of `mesh()` (if you use three arguments) basically set the x- and y- values. To get all three surfaces into the same plot you can use `hold on;`:

```
mesh(x_grid, y_grid, M)
hold on
mesh(x_grid, y_grid, a_grid)
mesh(x_grid, y_grid, b_grid)
```

Comment: What I need is a mathematical change of coordinates. So I need to plot the function represented by M vs the new coordinates a,b